# Creating COM Component in .NET - Is it possible to automatically register 'Implemented Categories'?

Tags: c#, .net, com

I'm creating a custom control in C# for a legacy application which only supports ActiveX. The control works fine in other applications, however the legacy application only checks the component category called 'Controls' and not the '.NET Category', so it doesn't show up in the list of available controls.

If I go into regedit and manually add the GUID for the 'Control' category to the Implemented Categories as below - the legacy application finds the control and inserts it no problem.

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXX}\Implemented Categories\{40FC6ED4-2438-11CF-A3DB-080036F12502}`

What I'm wondering is - is there an automated way to add such categories during build? During deployment, I don't want the engineers to have to go into the registry and add this category. Is creating a registry patch the only way to go?

I'm using a Visual Studio project to create an .msi file for deployment of the control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ComRegisterFunctionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comregisterfunctionattribute%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). It enables you to add abritrary registration code.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class MyClassThatNeedsToRegister
{
   Guid categoryGuid = ...;

   [ComRegisterFunctionAttribute]
   public static void RegisterFunction(Type t)
   {
       RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(
     "CLSID\\" + t.GUID.ToString("B") + 
     "\\Implemented Categories\\" + categoryGuid.ToString("B");
   }

   [ComUnregisterFunctionAttribute]
   public static void UnregisterFunction(Type t)
   {
      Registry.ClassesRoot.DeleteSubKey( "CLSID\\" + t.GUID.ToString("B") +
       "\\Implemented Categories\\" + categoryGuid.ToString("B"), false);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked on the same computer that the project was built on - but then I discovered that when packaged into a .msi installer, the installer doesn't call these register functions.

To get around that, I ended up adding the key to the Registry data in the installer project which worked.

Comment: The CLR calls the method with this attribute when its containing assembly is registered with the Regasm.exe. MSI setups don't call them. To call it from MSI you can create Custom Actions to run a command line `regasm.exe /codebase`

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense. Its strange though that the MSI installer doesn't call the register functions, even though it registers the COM object.

Comment: Preference is to have the information in the installer database rather than calling the external program in case it goes missing or fails to run for some reason and prevents repair/uninstall.  Custom actions to call regasm are not the preferred method for .msi